# Can an XMLDocument object be use with an XPathDocument object?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, .net-3.5, xpathnavigator

I have a static method that converts a html file and returns an XMLDocument object.

After doing extensive research, the following question has arised:

Can pass an XMLDocument object to a XPathDocument object, to make it easy when simply reading data from the document and not editing it.

[Research01](http://csharptutorial.blogspot.com/2006/10/reading-xml-fast.html)

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathdocument.aspx)

Please reply and let me know if this is possible? If so, how?

Cheers.

Comment: why do you need XPathDocument if you don't query it?

Comment: Oops, typo ... just edited it now.

Answer (score 1):

How are you reading data from the document? Both `XmlDocument` and `XPathDocument` have a `CreateNavigator` method that returns an `XPathNavigator` for reading the document. Otherwise, just stream the `XmlDocument` into a `MemoryStream` and create the `XPathDocument` from that.

Comment: Cheers dude ... I am using SGMLReader to produce my XML document. WHenever I feed this into a XPathDocument I get one root object with all the html passed into the inner text, which is useless for me :(